# Can't insert a new node in the binary tree

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree

I believe my insertion function is right, but it looks like the new node is not being inserted in the tree. I could not figure out where is the mistake. I appreciate any help,thanks.

There is the declaration of node and tree:

```
class Node{
     int key;
     Node *right, *left;
}

class Tree{
public:
      int init();
      Node *root;
      Node *insert(int key, Node *p);
};
```

there is the functions:

```
int Tree::init(){
    this->root = NULL;  return 1;
}

Node *Tree::insert(int key, Node *p){
  if(p == NULL){
    Node *novo = new Node();
    novo->key = key;
    novo->left = NULL;
    novo->right = NULL;
    p = novo;
    }
  else if(key < p->key){ p->left = insert(key, p->left); }
  else if(key > p->key){ p->right = insert(key, p->right); }
  else{ cout << "Error: key already exist" << endl; }

return p;
}
```

When I call the function in the main, it looks like it does not link the new node

```
int main() {
    Tree dictionary;

    cout << "enter the key"; cin >> key;   

    dictionary.insert(key, dictionary.root);

    cout << dictionary.root->key;
}
```

Comment: Off topic: why `int Tree::init()` instead of a constructor?

Comment: Your `MCVE` does not compile - I tried it with `gcc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your insert() function, when the tree is empty or if you've reached the last node, you create a new node:

```
if(p == NULL){
   Node *novo = new Node();
   novo->key = key;
   novo->left = NULL;
   novo->right = NULL;
   p = novo;              // ouch !!!! 
   }
```

Unfortunately, the statement `p=novo` only updates the local parameter `p` of your function.  Its value will vanish as soon as you return from the function.  It will not update the pointer with which you've called your function.  So the root of your tree remains NULL (or the left/right pointer of the last node).

To get the effect that you expect (i.e. your `p` assigment updates the root pointer or the pointer to left/right of the last node),  you need to change the signature to:

```
  Node *insert(int key, Node *& p);   // p is passed by reference
```

This will pass the pointer `p` by reference. Modifying p will then have the effect of modifying the pointer you used to call the function, and will endure a lasting effect of the insertion.

Comment: You forgot also to mention that he is passing an uninitialized variable `dictionary.root` in `main` and it can never work.

Comment: Thank you Christophe!!! It's a seally exercise but I could not notice this detail

Comment: @AlBundy yes, that's because OP forgot to call init().  Making a constructor instead of init() would avoid this kind of nasty bugs ;-)